# Divide form into different pages/views in angular

Tags: angular

I need to develop a SPA with angular 6 for insurance company. We have a form which has 9 questions. Customer wants one question should be displayed on the screen at a time and on clicking the button "Save & Continue",  next question should be appear on the screen.

For this scenario, can I create a parent component which holds 9 child components where each child component holds one question and only component would be visible and remaining 8 would be hidden always?

Is that the right approach(hide/show components) to follow?

Comment: Your question is highly subjective. If the fields are simple, going with an "index visible" approach is probably easier. If the fields are complex, and it makes sense to encapsulate functionality into separate components, then take that approach. Otherwise, the correct answer is "whatever is easiest for you (and others) to maintain and extend"

Answer (score 0):

No this approach is not the right approach. Instead create a list of questions and then update question displayed in a component on( Save and continue) click event. Once all questions are displayed and use click on save and continue for the last question then redirect him/her to another component.

Comment: You should add a code example to enhance your answer.